# Boxplot with geom_boxplot for many years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make nice boxplot with ggplot2.
NB: the airquality data from ggplot2 can illustrated what I want to do but in my own data I have an additional column for year(1900:2000).

I make simple boxplot with this command:

```
      tapply(data$Temp, substr(data$Month, 1,3),na.rm=TRUE, summary) #data=airquality
      boxplot(Temp~Month, data=data, na.action = NULL, main="1900-2000")
```

It have this graphic:
[image: Graph1]

But I when try with ggplot2 with this command:

```
     ggplot(data, aes(Month, Temp),facet= Month~.) + geom_boxplot()
```

It get this graphic
[image: Graph2]

In the same plot I want to view the corresponding Value and boxplot for each month like graphic1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Month` is a continuous variable you will need to 'factorize' this variable to have seperate boxplots:

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(factor(Month), Temp)) + geom_boxplot()
```

alternatively you can use the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(airquality, aes(Month, Temp, group = Month)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thank's it's work but I want to have the corresponding value of quartile in the same plot.

Comment: What does your statement mean? Your original plot does not seem to have labeling on the quartile values?

Comment: Hi @Vlo You are right but I don't know how to add quartile valuesin the plot.

Comment: You can use the follow pseudo-code `geom_text(aes(x = func1(), y = func2(), labels = c("25th", "50th", "75th"))`, where `func1()` and `func2()` just output x, y values for the text label positions. I assume you already know that the boxplot box edges are the 25, 50th and 75th percentile right?